# Exception with Django 1.6.5 and factory_boy

Tags: django, factory-boy

I decided to use factory_boy in my simple django application for test purposes.
But I had a problem with simple example. Here is the code of my simple test.

```
from django.utils import unittest
from ..models import Server, ServerAddress, L2TPServer, serialize_open_vpn_server_json

from factory import django as django_factory


class SshOpenVpnServerFactory(django_factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = L2TPServer
        django_get_or_create = ('name', 'address')

    name = 'Hello'
    address = 'Nono'


class ServersTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_serialize_server_info(self):
        print Server.objects.all()
        SshOpenVpnServerFactory.build()
```

When test-runner executes this test, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/green/Development/Wasel/experimental/wasel_services/packages/waselcore/backend/tests/test_models.py", line 20, in test_serialize_server_info
    SshOpenVpnServerFactory.build()
  File "/Users/green/Development/Wasel/experimental/env/wasel_sevices/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 504, in build
    attrs = cls.attributes(create=False, extra=kwargs)
  File "/Users/green/Development/Wasel/experimental/env/wasel_sevices/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 365, in attributes
    force_sequence=force_sequence,
  File "/Users/green/Development/Wasel/experimental/env/wasel_sevices/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/containers.py", line 265, in build
    sequence = self.factory._generate_next_sequence()
  File "/Users/green/Development/Wasel/experimental/env/wasel_sevices/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 338, in _generate_next_sequence
    cls._setup_counter()
  File "/Users/green/Development/Wasel/experimental/env/wasel_sevices/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 318, in _setup_counter
    first_seq = cls._setup_next_sequence()
  File "/Users/green/Development/Wasel/experimental/env/wasel_sevices/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 83, in _setup_next_sequence
    manager = cls._get_manager(model)
  File "/Users/green/Development/Wasel/experimental/env/wasel_sevices/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 76, in _get_manager
    return target_class.objects
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Where am I wrong? Does factory_boy support django 1.6.5?

Comment: Nevermind my comment, I found the answer; see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proposed syntax using the `Meta` class will only be released as part of the (unreleased) Factory Boy 2.4. Use `SshOpenVpnServerFactory.FACTORY_FOR` instead. Related issue: https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy/issues/143

Comment: 2.4 has been released 2014-06-21